# Nested scrolling divs not working on older Android Native browsers using CSS3 overflow-x and overflow-y

Tags: overflow, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I have a problem with Android browsers below version 4, where I have a parent scrollable div, with vertical scrolling enabled via CSS property overflow-y:auto, and a nested child div (smaller in size than parent) with overflow-x:auto horizontal scrolling enabled.

In every other browser, when touching the nested horizontal scrolling div, and moving up or down, the vertical scrolling kicks in, and the outer div scrolls vertically, which is how I would expect it to behave.

On older Android browsers, when doing this, no vertically scrolling occurs. When debugging we found that in this situation no touchmove or scroll events fire when moving touch up or down. They fire correctly, as you would expect, when moving left or right, horizontally.

Good phones to see this on are HTC One X and Samsung S3.

The HTML page test app below demonstrates the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    #childScrollableDiv {
      height: 300px;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      width: 600px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      white-space: nowrap;       
    }
    #parentScrollableDiv {
      height: 600px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      width: 600px;
      border: 0px;         
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body class=''>
  <div style="color:red">

    <p>some text outer
      <p>some text outer
        <p>some text outer

          <div style="color:green" id="parentScrollableDiv">
            <p>some text
              <p>some text
                <p>some text
                  <p>some text
                    <p>some text
                      <p>some text
                        <p>some text
                          <p>some text
                            <p>some text
                              <p>some text

                                <div style="color:blue" id="childScrollableDiv">
                                  <p>internal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal text
                                    <p>internal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal text
                                      <p>internal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal text
                                        <p>internal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal text
                                          <p>internal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal text
                                            <p>internal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal text
                                              <p>internal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal textinternal text internal textinternal textinternal text
                                </div>

                                <p>some text
                                  <p>some text
                                    <p>some text
                                      <p>some text
                                        <p>some text
                                          <p>some text
                                            <p>some text
                                              <p>some text
                                                <p>some text
                                                  <p>some text
          </div>

          <p>some text outer
            <p>some text outer
              <p>some text outer

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```